# Espresso Idling Resource doesn't work

Tags: android, android-espresso

The Android espresso is very useful for test case. But when I use `IdlingResource` there is some trouble.

I have a flag in my `Activity`, and I will set it to `true` when every initial complete.

So my IdlingResource is this:

```
/**
 * 等待所有初始化工作完成
 */
private class WaitPingSuccessIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {
    private ChoiceServerActivity choiceServerActivity;
    private ResourceCallback mResourceCallback;

    public WaitPingSuccessIdlingResource(ChoiceServerActivity choiceServerActivity) {
        this.choiceServerActivity = choiceServerActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return String.valueOf(hashCode());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isIdleNow() {
        if (mResourceCallback != null && choiceServerActivity.isAllDataInited()) {
            mResourceCallback.onTransitionToIdle();
        }
        boolean rst = choiceServerActivity.isAllDataInited();
        Log.i("tonghu","WaitPingSuccessIdlingResource, isIdleNow(L94): rst " + rst);
        return rst;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback callback) {
        this.mResourceCallback = callback;
    }
}
```

And I register like this:

```
Espresso.registerIdlingResources(new WaitPingSuccessIdlingResource(activity));
Log.i("tonghu", "ChoiceServerActivityTest, testPingSuccess(L42): 2222");
```

In normally, the second log will print only when `isIdleNow()` return `true`.

But now my log is:

```
I/tonghu  (23470): WaitPingSuccessIdlingResource, isIdleNow(L94): rst false
I/tonghu  (23470): ChoiceServerActivityTest, testPingSuccess(L42): 2222
```

Why the second log can print when my IdlingResource wasn't idle.

My English is poor, any problem, please let me know! Thx!

---

**EDITED:**
I have already solve this problem:

I see there is a comment on class `IdlingResource`:

```
In such cases, test authors can register the custom resource and 
{@link    Espresso} will wait for the resource to become idle prior 
to   executing a view operation.
```

So after register Idling resource, just give any a view action:

```
Espresso.registerIdlingResources(new  WaitPingSuccessIdlingResource(activity));
Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.list_view)).check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()));
```

Comment: Check this library: https://github.com/metova/Cappuccino

Comment: I had a similar problem. It's a bummer that `IdlingResource` will only wait for view actions, not all code.

Comment: Also Cappuccino isn't going to help you there. IdlingResource still will only happen on view action

Answer (score 5):

Same problem here, found that registering idlingResources won't cause Espresso to wait, but besides `Espresso.onView`, you still can use `Espresso.onIdle()` to wait for registered idlingResources to turn idle.

Finally, I found the official document, quote from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource):

> **Register idling resources before you need them.**
>
> The synchronization benefits associated with idling resources only take effect following Espresso's first invocation of that resource's
>   isIdleNow() method.
>
> The following list shows several examples of this property:
>
> 1. If you register an idling resource in a method annotated with
>      @Before, the idling resource takes effect in the first line of each
>      test.
> 2. If you register an idling resource inside a test, the idling resource takes effect during the next Espresso-based action. This
>      behavior still occurs even if the next action is in the same test as
>      the statement that registers the idling resource.

Comment: Note: in `com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1` `Espresso.onIdle()` doesn't wait for just-registered Idling Resources (via `IdlingRegistry.register`), only `onView`/`onData` does, see `sync` call in the beginning of those methods.